# Срез текстовой строчки из CSV файла

Tags: python

Прошу помочь получить срез. Есть строчка CSV файла -

```
 Петров,Васильев,Иванов,Сидоров,Птичкин
```

необходимо получить только слово после второй запятой и до третьей (слово Иванов)

пример среза для первого слова -

```
var0.set(value[value.find('')+0 : value.find(',')])
```

пример среза для последнего слова -

```
var2.set(value[value.find(',')+1 : value.find('')-1])
```

Слова после запятых могут быть с любым количеством.

Comment: С любым количеством чего?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, то можно сделать так:

```py
# Пример 1
# Строка из примера
csv_str = "Петров,Васильев,Иванов,Сидоров,Птичкин"

# Разделение строки по запятой и получение нужной части по индексу
new_str = csv_str.split(",")[2]

print(new_str)

# Пример 2
# В исходную строку добавил дополнительных фамилий
csv_str = "Петров,Васильев,Иванов Сидоров Птичкин,Сидоров,Птичкин"
# Срез от второго элемента [индекс 2] до третьего элемента [индекс 3]
str_slice = csv_str.split(',')[2:3]

# Склеиваем в строку
result = ','.join(str_slice)

print(result)
```

Вывод в консоль:

> Иванов

> Иванов Сидоров Птичкин

Comment: ``[2]`` и ``[2:3]`` это одно и то же.

Comment: @Эникейщик [2] - верну строку 'Иванов Сидоров Птичкин', а так [2:3] - верну список ['Иванов Сидоров Птичкин']. Разве это одно и тоже?

Comment: А, ну с этой точки зрения разное

Comment: Все супер, целый день искал как реализовать. Огромное спасибо.